# Chef/Ruby: use "each do" block variable with node attribute

Tags: chef, ruby, opsworks

Chef 11.10.4 environment running in AWS Opsworks.

**I can't figure out how to pass the value of the "each do" block variable, "lyr," below, with the node attribute `node['aws-tag'][#{lyr}]`?**

The code block below works from lines 02-06 but NOT from lines 07-14.

```
[01] include_recipe "aws"
[02] unless node['aws-tag']['tags'].empty? || node['aws-tag']['tags'].nil?
[03]    aws_resource_tag node['ec2']['instance_id'] do
[04]        tags(node['aws-tag']['tags'])
[05]        action :update
[06]    end
[07]    node['opsworks']['instance']['layers'].each do |lyr|
[08]        unless node['aws-tag'][#{lyr}].empty? || node['aws-tag'][#{lyr}].nil?
[09]            aws_resource_tag node['ec2']['instance_id'] do
[10]                tags(node['aws-tag'][#{lyr}])
[11]                action :update
[12]            end
[13]        end
[14]    end
[15] end
```

Here are the results from chef-shell showing the values of the attributes referenced in the code above:

chef > node['opsworks']['instance']['layers']
 => ["mongodb"]

chef > node['aws-tag']
 => {"tags"=>{"application"=>"app1", "environment"=>"dev"}, "mongodb"=>{"service"=>"mongodb"}}

NOTE: I'm modifying the [chef-aws-tag](https://github.com/stuart-warren/chef-aws-tag) cookbook to tag all ec2 instances with the tags in `node['aws-tag']['tags']` and in addition to tag each ec2 instance opsworks layer specific tags that are included in custom json passed to opsworks by layer, in this case the contents of `node['aws-tag']['mongodb']` or `node['aws-tag']['LAYER']`, generically.

If I run the code above I get a recipe compile error: "unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting ']'" -- see below for the detailed error message from opsworks:

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/chef-aws-tag/recipes/ec2.rb
================================================================================


SyntaxError
-----------
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/chef-aws-tag/recipes/ec2.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting ']'
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/chef-aws-tag/recipes/ec2.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ']'


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:30:in `instance_eval'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:30:in `from_file'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb:237:in `load_recipe'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/run_context.rb:151:in `load_recipe'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:139:in `block in compile_recipes'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:137:in `each'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:137:in `compile_recipes'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:74:in `compile'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/run_context.rb:86:in `load'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/policy_builder/expand_node_object.rb:75:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/client.rb:252:in `setup_run_context'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/client.rb:413:in `do_run'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/client.rb:200:in `block in run'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/client.rb:194:in `fork'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/client.rb:194:in `run'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/application.rb:215:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:314:in `block in run_application'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:306:in `loop'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:306:in `run_application'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/application.rb:66:in `run'
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/aws/opsworks/current/bin/chef-client:16:in `load'
/opt/aws/opsworks/current/bin/chef-client:16:in `<main>'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20141010064749_328/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chef-11.10.4/lib/chef/mixin/from_file.rb:

23: 
24:        # Loads a given ruby file, and runs instance_eval against it in the context of the current
25:        # object.
26:        #
27:        # Raises an IOError if the file cannot be found, or is not readable.
28:        def from_file(filename)
29:          if File.exists?(filename) && File.readable?(filename)
30>>           self.instance_eval(IO.read(filename), filename, 1)
31:          else
32:            raise IOError, "Cannot open or read #{filename}!"
33:          end
34:        end
35: 
36:        # Loads a given ruby file, and runs class_eval against it in the context of the current
37:        # object.
38:        #
39:        # Raises an IOError if the file cannot be found, or is not readable.



[2014-10-28T17:43:22+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-10-28T17:43:22+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-10-28T17:43:22+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-10-28T17:43:22+00:00] ERROR: /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/chef-aws-tag/recipes/ec2.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting ']'
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/chef-aws-tag/recipes/ec2.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ']'
[2014-10-28T17:43:22+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: #{variable} is used for string interpolation, and it is not in quotes.  I am not running the code, but I am surprised it is not raising errors for you as the rest of that line from the octothorpe on should be considered a comment.

Comment: @vgoff -- I understand that I am using a string interpolation.  I am new to ruby/chef and don't know how to do it with a non string which is why I posted the question.  I attached the error output to the original question.

Comment: Ah, but you aren't using String Interpolation, though it appears you want to.  Wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 8 looks suspect to me, should raise errors, as indicated...

```
unless node['aws-tag'][#{lyr}].empty? || node['aws-tag'][#{lyr}].nil?
```

Should be string interpolation, but it isn't.

Try this line:

```
unless node['aws-tag']["#{lyr}"].empty? || node['aws-tag']["#{lyr}"].nil?
```

If `lyr` is already a string, then simply use `lyr` like so:

```
unless node['aws-tag'][lyr].empty? || node['aws-tag'][lyr].nil?
```